# return string when using the builder Pattern and Method chaining in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to use the Builder pattern and use that by method chaining.

This is my class:

```
public class SQLGenerator : ISQLGenerator
{
    private readonly SQLGeneratorModel generatorModel;
    public SQLGenerator()
    {
        generatorModel = new SQLGeneratorModel();
    }

    public ISQLGenerator From(string TableName)
    {
        generatorModel.TabelName = string.Format("FROM {0}", TableName);
        return this;
    }

    public ISQLGenerator Select(List<string> SelectItems)
    {
        StringBuilder select = new StringBuilder();
        var lastItem = SelectItems.Last();
        foreach (var item in SelectItems)
        {
            if (!item.Equals(lastItem))
            {
                select.Append(item).Append(" , ");
            }
            else
            {
                select.Append(item);
            }
        }
        generatorModel.Select =string.Format("SELECT {0}", select.ToString());
        return this;
    }
```

This is how this class is used:

```
SQLGenerator generator = new SQLGenerator();
List<string> select = new List<string>();
select.Add("id");
select.Add("Name");
var str = generator.Select(select).From("AppUsers");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Now I expect a string to be returned like this: `SELECT ID , NAME FROM APPUSER` but it shows me this result in the console:

`SqlPagingGenerator.Pattern.SQLGenerator`

How can I show the string result?

Comment: Change `var str` to `string str` and you will see the problem

Comment: yes i know my question is this `how can i convert SqlPagingGenerator.Pattern.SQLGeneratorto string ???`

Comment: If you want to use the builder pattern you should have the method `Build` and you should call it in the end to obtain the result (string in your case) instead of `ISQLGenerator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you are returning an object from the method not a string.
All you have to do is to override the `ToString` method of your class to return the string you want.

```
    public class SQLGenerator : ISQLGenerator
    {
        ....
        public override string ToString()
        {
           return  $"{generatorModel.TableName} {generatorModel.Select}";
        }

    }
```